# d3.scale on JSON Data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to enable domain and range finding on JSON data with D3.  I can easily do so with hard-coded numbers but I'm unsure what I should do for JSON data I'm looking for.

For hard-coded numbers, I can easily get something I'm looking for:

```
var test = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([200,1000]);

console.log(test(900)); // returns an obvious value adjusted for scale
```

But for a JSON Object I'm getting an error "cannot read property map of undefined" in my console.  Obviously user error:

```
var test = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(testData['Sources']['Value']);

console.log(test(900)); // returns "cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

Should I somehow be doing a for-each on the JSON data, or D3's .enter() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indeed need to iterate over the elements in your data, but D3 offers functions that make this easier. For example:

```
var test = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(d3.extent(testData, function(d) { return d['Sources']['Value']; }));
```

This tells D3 to get `['Sources']['Value']` for every element in `testData` and return the min and max values in an array. I'm assuming that this is the format of your data, if not, adjust appropriately.

Comment: Perfect!  when I console.log(test(some-number)); I do get NaN error though.  Currently looking into .extent() some more, but any idea why that may be?

Comment: What does your data look like?

Comment: var testData = {
     Sources: [
      {
       Source: "Test0",
       Value: .6
      },
      {
       Source: "Test1",
       Value: .1
      },
      {
       Source: "Test2",
       Value: .3
      }   
     ]
    };

Comment: Ok, so it would be `d3.extent(testData.Sources, function(d) { return d['Value']; })`.

Comment: D'oh. I've been looking at this too long, didn't even realize.